# How to send message automatically to user as well as admin using Firebase in Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, automation, chat, messaging

I am making a chat app in for user and admin where all the user can talk to an admin and Admin can chat to all the user personally. but I want to show user some welcome messages from admin side before the user can message anything or you can say some automated message.

Something like this :

[image]

I have used Firebase Realtime database to store the chats. and Firestore to store user-admin personal data.

Not getting any clue how to do it. If anyone can help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can create an auto-generated message each time someone starts a new conversation, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo  Yeah , how to do that , I am not very clear. pls could you guide me how to go about it?

Comment: In the way you are adding the first message of the admin, simply add an auto-generated message.